# How exactly does javascript set context for objects created from constructor function using the new keyword

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, this, arrow-functions

Consider the following constructor function having a method logging the context

```
function Foo() {
  this.logContext1 = () => console.log('logContext1', this);
}

let foo = new Foo();

foo.logContext2 = () => console.log('logContext2', this);

foo.logContext1();
foo.logContext2();
```

logContext1 has context (`this`) set to the Foo object created by new,

whereas logContext2 has context (`this`) set to the window object

Considering both are arrow functions, why do we see this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is defined where the [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are declared:

- `() => console.log('logContext1', this)` is declared in the constructor, `this` is the object being created in that context
- `() => console.log('logContext2', this)` is declared on top-level, `this` is `window` in that context (or `undefined` in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))

Comment: so in case of arrow functions, `this` binding depends where it is declared / defined rather than how it is called

Comment: Well yes, exactly